# Clojure Koans recursive is-even?

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm working through Clojure Koans and I'm up to the recursion koans.

I don't understand how to solve `is-even?` using recursion. The exercise partially defines this function as:

```
(defn is-even? [n]
    (if (= n 0)
        true
        (__ (is-even? (dec n)))))
```

If I don't want to use recursion then I would define it as `(defn is-even? [n] (= (mod n 2) 0))` but that goes against the point of the exercise.

Comment: This Koan is easier to understand if you do not start solving the `is-even?` function, but instead if you start with the first Koan in the `meditations` block. This is a bit confusing, but the koans slowly build it up and that is where you need to start.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like amalloy said, fill the blanks with "not". But provided you assume the argument can only be 0 or positive, you don't need another base case: `dec` makes sure you always end up at 0, and odd numbers return false like this:

```
(is-even? 0) ==> base case (= 0 0) ==> true.
(is-even? 1) ==> (not (is-even? (dec 1))
             ==> (not (is-even? 0))
             ==> (not true)
             ==> false
(is-even? 2) ==> (not (is-even? 1))
             ==> (not false)
             ==> true
```

etcetera.

Answer (score 10):

A number `n` is even if either:

1. `n` is 0
2. `n-1` is NOT even

So really, `not` should be enough to fill in that blank. Eventually you wind up with N `not`s around `(= 0 0)`, and most of them cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider decrementing by 2 for each recursion. The rest should be obvious: The number is even only if the function ends up with zero.

EDIT: Apparently I missed the memo about filling in the blank. Here is the tail call optimizable solution I had in mind for positive integers:

```
(defn is-even? [n]
    (if (<= n 1)
        (= n 0)
        (is-even? (- n 2))))
```

Comment: you can use the `recur` function for tail call optimization