# Trying to understand recursion in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm a beginner and really trying to understand so please bear with me.

I'm working through the Clojure Koans, and I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around recursion.

I'm stuck on this problem: [Clojure Koans recursive is-even?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853726/clojure-koans-recursive-is-even)

This is the correct function:

```
(defn is-even? [n]
    (if (= n 0)
        true
        (not (is-even? (dec n)))))
```

These are great examples that are given:

```
(is-even? 0) ==> base case (= 0 0) ==> true.
(is-even? 1) ==> (not (is-even? (dec 1))
             ==> (not (is-even? 0))
             ==> (not true)
             ==> false
(is-even? 2) ==> (not (is-even? 1))
             ==> (not false)
             ==> true
```

But I'm confused about why the recursion doesn't keep happening until you are left with 0 every time.

For example, with n=2. Here is how I reason what happens in my head: 2 does not equal 0, so then
(not (is-even? 1)) gets evaluated. When this gets evaluated, 1 gets plugged into the is-even? function. Because 1 doesn't equal 0, this statement is false, but wouldn't this false statement get passed to (not (is-even? (dec 1))? And for all n>0, they would keep getting decreased in this loop until they equal 0?

I feel like there are some basic concepts I don't understand :( I really appreciate all input and hope to learn a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I follow what you're asking but perhaps the confusion comes from the way they've written out the example for `(is-even? 2)` because they've taken a shortcut and gone from `(not (is-even? 1))` directly to `(not false)` instead of walking through the same steps they'd already shown for `(is-even? 1)` above, namely that it is treated as `(not (is-even? (dec 1)))` which is `(not (is-even? 0))` which is `(not true)` -- and they jump straight to `false`.

Does that clarify what the examples mean? If not, can you try to articulate where you are getting lost in example?

Comment: Thanks Sean, adding that extra step helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm confused about why the recursion doesn't keep happening until
> you are left with 0 every time.

It does. The succession of evaluations is

```
(is-even? 2)
(not (is-even? 1))
(not (not (is-even? 0)))
(not (not true))
(not false)
true
```

For any positive `long` `n`, we get a cascade of `n` `not`s wrapped around `(is-even? 0)`.

- The `(is-even? 0)` evaluates to `true`.
- Every two `not`s cancel one another.
- So,

  - if `n` is even, we have no `not`s left, and the function evaluates
    `true`; otherwise,
  - if `n` is odd, we have one `not` left, and the function evaluates
    `(not true)`, i.e. `false`.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! Somehow I wasn't keeping in mind all the not's that keep getting added. Thank you!